# my android 3g isnt working but i can make an receive calls.. what could be the problem?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I can make calls and text but when it comes to the internet i cant use it. The 3g symbol is there but its not lit up like its suppose to be. I need help with figuring this out so please help me fix this?! I've tried restarting it. And it does the same exact thing. like i'm confused cause its never done this before. what more could i do to fix this problem? I can text perfectly fine make calls the same way. But can not use my internet.

Comment: You could have disabled mobile data (3G) so your phone is working on 2G, which allows only calls and texts. Try going to settings -> data usage and check the 'cellular data' option.

Comment: the company had to rest my phone

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! So your issue is solved now? If so, you could [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) and accept the answer, to make that obvious to others with a similar issue. Thanks!